How to reduce the polycount of an mesh?
I imported a dress I made in Clo3d to Blender, but it has 5 million triangles and similar in vertices and edges, how can I reduce poly count so it doesn't make my project slow?


If you use decimate, you first put the object in edit mode, hit 'a' to select all vertices (or an area to decimate), and then when you "cleanup -> decimate" you need to change the Ratio parameter from 1.0 (nothing) to something like 0.5 (50% fewer vertices).
